# Linux xfce4 with login user command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c++, xfce4

I have a Linux Ubuntu 20.04 computer running Xubuntu. I am in the process of writing a c ++ program that consists of a completely new login screen. This login screen also works and I can check whether the password I entered is correct. But now I somehow need a way to actually log the user into the Linux system. Currently the command `sudo xfce4-session` is simply executed after a successful data entry. Everything works great, but unfortunately the Xfce4 desktop always starts as root. But I don't want that. How can I somehow enter the user who is logged in when starting the desktop with the command `sudo xfce4-session` or how can I otherwise start a session so that another nurse is automatically logged in when the command is executed. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: why are you starting xfce4 via sudo in the first place? You're literally *telling* it to start as root

Comment: If I run this command as not root, I always get an error message that the user does not have sufficient rights. I've tried everything to get rid of this error, but without success. It basically means that I have no rights to access the ad. From my point of view, this also makes sense, since I also start the X server as root beforehand. I also have to start this as root, as it needs the appropriate rights for authentication.